# Trying to rerun a class in java

Tags: java

I posted a question here recently but I was not specific enough so I reduced my code to the bare minimum. I'm trying to use joption pane to ask the user to rerun the program but it only runs once or I recieve the error "method main in class FahrenheitToCelcius cannot be applied to given types" I don't know what to put for main on the rerun while statement.

```
public class FahrenheitToCelcius
{   
public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
    FahCel conv = new FahCel();
    conv.setFahren();
    conv.getCel();
    Rerun();
    System.exit(0);       
    } 
    public static void Rerun()  
    {
    int answer;
    answer = 0;
    answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "Click 'yes' to run again or 'no' to exit",
            "Rerun Program?",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    while (answer == 0) 
            {
                main;
                answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "Click 'yes' to run again or 'no' to exit",
            "Rerun Program?",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }        
      }
   }
```

And the class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FahCel 
{
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
private double Fahr;
private double FinalC;

public void setFahren()
{
    System.out.println("Total number of degrees in Fahrenheit to be Converted into Celcius?");
    Fahr = keyboard.nextInt();
}
public void getCel()
{
    FinalC = 5/9.0*(Fahr-32);
    System.out.println("Temperature in Celcius is: " + FinalC);
}   
}
```

Comment: What do you think the line `main;` does and why is in in your code? That line causes your compilation error.

Comment: You should not try to use the `main()` method like that. Better then to have your own "main" but with a different name. Off-topic, you do not need to call `System.exit()` at the end of  `main()`

Comment: System.exit(0); Will exit the JVM and thus all threads associated with the JVM

Comment: @TungstenX and how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: @ehlert5290 I suggest you refactor your code so you have no need to call `main`. It can surely be done with a while loop inside `main`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments I'll use a while loop!

Answer (score 0):

By "rerunning a class" you seem to want to run the `main` method again. Even though I don't recommend doing that, your current problem can be solved.

You try to call `main` but you don't pass the necessary parameters that the method requires, which is a `String[]`.

Replace

```
main;
```

with

```
main(new String[0]);
```

and you can then "re-run your class". But I doubt that this is what you actually want.